# Compile C code with /clr option

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have library project that is compiled with /CLR option. Now I need to connect to WCF server using native CPP WCF client. During compilation I got error

```
Error   1   error D8045: cannot compile C file 'schemas.microsoft.com.2003.10.Serialization.xsd.c' with the /clr option
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hmm, pretty unclear what you hope to accomplish with WCF from a C source file.  Anyhoo, the /CLR option requires a C++ source file.  A starting point is to force it to get compiled as C++, might just work.  Right-click the file > Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Compile As = Compile as C++ Code.

Comment: Or just rename the file as `.cpp`, less confusing for you when you come back and see C++ syntax in a C file, or try to add it to another project.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thx, I actually had the opposite case, having C file with C++ option configured. changing to C made it work. 3

Answer (score 2):

Use the `/TP` flag to force the CLR compiler to treat it like a C++ file:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abb82cy0(VS.80).aspx